# Is there a difference between using .begin() vs .end() for std::inserter for std::set?

Tags: c++, stl, stdset, insert-iterator

If there is any difference between it1 and it2?

```
std::set<sometype> s;

auto it1 = std::inserter(s, s.begin());
auto it2 = std::inserter(s, s.end());
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation? This is really easy to find out via googling.

Comment: well, they are two different iterators, does that help? aside from that, you'll be splitting hairs... (i.e. profile to find out!)

Comment: @Nim - I wonder how it is written in standard

Comment: if you mean the C++ standard, you'll have to ask one of the standards lawyers on this site.. I haven't a clue... As for usage, frankly I think it's daft that this *hint* has to be provided in the first place, but if I had to use it, I'd always use `end()`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In practice, not much.  If you're inserting a large number of already in order elements into an empty `set`, the second will be somewhat faster, but that's about it.  `std::insert_iterator` calls `insert` with the iterator; `std::set` interprets it as a hint, and inserts in constant time (rather than lg n) if the insertion is immediately before the hint.  (Actually, if the `set` is empty, I think both will do exactly the same thing.)

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/insert_iterator.html

In the case of a Sorted Associative Container, however, the iterator in the insert_iterator's constructor is almost irrelevant. The new elements will not necessarily form a contiguous range; they will appear in the appropriate location in the container, in ascending order by key. The order in which they are inserted only affects efficiency: inserting an already-sorted range into a Sorted Associative Container is an O(N) operation.